# reseting checkbox on reset button click in titanium

Tags: titanium

i googled and found below code which creats checkbox .but these check boxes get selected when i click both the checkbox.my requirement is, i need one check box is checked while other is unchecked.that is one checkbox has to be checked at a time .and pressing reset button all the check box should be unchecked.

```
 var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({backgroundColor:"white"});
 var checkbox = Ti.UI.createSwitch({
style:Ti.UI.Android.SWITCH_STYLE_CHECKBOX,
title:"male",
value:true
 });

win.add(checkbox);
checkbox.addEventListener("change", function(e){
Ti.API.info("The checkbox has been set to " + e.value);
});
  var checkbox1 = Ti.UI.createSwitch({
style:Ti.UI.Android.SWITCH_STYLE_CHECKBOX,
title:"female",
value:true
 });

win.add(checkbox1);
checkbox1.addEventListener("change", function(e){
Ti.API.info("The checkbox has been set to " + e.value);
});
var resetbtn = Ti.UI.createButton({
top : '100',
width : '50',
height : '35',
title  : 'Reset'
});
win1.add(resetbtn);
resetbtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
checkbox.value='';
 }
win.open();
```

please help me i am new to titanium,i want checkbox should be unclicked on presing resetbutton press and one checkbox as to get clicked at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your query you want the following thing :

1. You need one check box is checked while other is unchecked i'e,
       one checkbox has to be checked at a time.
2. Pressing reset button all the check box should be unchecked.

For Point 1 : Here is the code for this point :

```
     var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({backgroundColor:"white"});

     var checkbox = Ti.UI.createSwitch({
         style:Ti.UI.Android.SWITCH_STYLE_CHECKBOX,
         title:"male",
         value:true,
         width: "200dp", height:"120dp", left:"10dp"
     });

     win.add(checkbox);
     checkbox.addEventListener("change", function(e){
         Ti.API.info("The checkbox has been set to " + e.value);
         if(e.value) {
            checkbox1.value=false;
         } else {
            checkbox1.value=true;
         }
    });

    var checkbox1 = Ti.UI.createSwitch({
      style:Ti.UI.Android.SWITCH_STYLE_CHECKBOX,
      title:"female",
      value:true
   });

   win.add(checkbox1);
   checkbox1.addEventListener("change", function(e){
      Ti.API.info("The checkbox has been set to " + e.value);
      if(e.value) {
         checkbox.value=false;
      } else {
        checkbox.value=true;
      }
   });
   var resetbtn = Ti.UI.createButton({
   top : '100',
   width : '50',
   height : '35',
   title  : 'Reset'
   });
   win.add(resetbtn);

   resetbtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
       Ti.API.info('Refresh button click');

   });

   win.open();
```

For point 2 : I am just code as per your need but this not the right way i think. If you want to reset checkbox with your requirement (one checkbox has to be checked at a time) then better to use image for checkbox or radio-button. But Here is the code for that :

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({backgroundColor:"white"});
var checkFlag = true;
var resetTouch = false;
 var checkbox = Ti.UI.createSwitch({
style:Ti.UI.Android.SWITCH_STYLE_CHECKBOX,
title:"male",
value:true,
width: "200dp", height:"120dp", left:"10dp"
 });

win.add(checkbox);
checkbox.addEventListener("change", function(e){
Ti.API.info("The checkbox has been set to " + e.value);
if(e.value) {
    checkbox1.value=false;
} else {
    checkbox1.value=true;
}


});
  var checkbox1 = Ti.UI.createSwitch({
style:Ti.UI.Android.SWITCH_STYLE_CHECKBOX,
title:"female",
value:true
 });

win.add(checkbox1);
checkbox1.addEventListener("change", function(e){
Ti.API.info("The checkbox has been set to " + e.value);
if(e.value) {
    checkbox.value=false;
} else {
    checkbox.value=true;
}
});
var resetbtn = Ti.UI.createButton({
top : '100',
width : '50',
height : '35',
title  : 'Reset'
});
win.add(resetbtn);

var checkboxNew = Ti.UI.createSwitch({
    style:Ti.UI.Android.SWITCH_STYLE_CHECKBOX,
    title:"male",
    value:false,
    width: "200dp", height:"120dp", left:"10dp"
 });
win.add(checkboxNew);

var checkboxNew1 = Ti.UI.createSwitch({
    style:Ti.UI.Android.SWITCH_STYLE_CHECKBOX,
    title:"female",
    value:false
});

win.add(checkboxNew1);

resetbtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    Ti.API.info('checkFlag = ' + checkFlag);
    if(checkFlag) {
        checkbox.hide();
        checkbox1.hide();
        checkboxNew.show();
        checkboxNew1.show();

        checkFlag = false;
    } else {
        checkbox.show();
        checkbox1.show();
        checkboxNew.hide();
        checkboxNew1.hide();

        checkFlag = true;
    }

});
checkboxNew.addEventListener("change", function(e){
    Ti.API.info("The checkboxNew has been set to " + e.value);
    checkboxNew.value=false;
    checkboxNew1.value=false;

});
checkboxNew1.addEventListener("change", function(e){
    Ti.API.info("The checkboxNew1 has been set to " + e.value);
    checkboxNew.value=false;
    checkboxNew1.value=false;

});
checkbox.hide();
checkbox1.hide();
checkboxNew.show();
checkboxNew1.show();


win.open();
```

Please Take a look on it.

Comment: thanks for guiding me i actually needed a code like when i click on one checkbox it has to check(if it is checked already uncheck)while other should not change .exactly it has to behave like radio button.i modified  your code to get my requirment and  its working

Comment: i am actually developing a form in which it has to check whether user as selected at least one checkbox what is the condition i have to use to validate that condition or how could i do that.please guide me

Comment: Means you want to validate the form with at least one checkbox selected.
For this you need to set a flag or variable
(equals to 0) and increase the value when checkbox selected (their event listener) and decrease the variable when checkbox unselected.
And the submission time of form you can validate by the value of variable (by compare with 0).